Understanding the definition for 講座
I have trouble making sense of the definition for 講座:

こう‐ざ【講座】(カウ━)〘名〙
❶ 大学で、学科ごとに教授・准教授・講師などを配した研究・教育のための組織。また、それに基づいて行われる講義。

I am unsure how to understand 学科ごとに. There are two ways I can read the bold part:

An organization located in a university for research and education which allocated professors, associate professors and lecturers for each subject (I am assuming that the subject for 配した is 組織).

An organization located in a university for research and education, which is different for each subject...


You can see that #2 treats 講座 as something that is different for each 学科, whereas in #1, 講座 is seen as a entity that assigns professors in each subject. I think #2 makes sense.
How ごとに works here grammatically?

The adverbial form ごとに can only go with 配した in this sentence. Where did you get "different" from?

学科ごとに modifies 配した, and this phrase normally means "on a per-学科 basis" or "for each 学科". However, 学科ごとに教授を配する sounds like each 学科 has only one professor, which is clearly incorrect. Each 学科 in a university typically has 10 or more 教授. So this dictionary definition appears misleading, and it should have been something like 学科内で or 学科の下部組織として instead.

学科 in a context like this is not "subject" but "department". 学科 (department) is a subclass of 学部 (faculty), and many 講座 (chair/course) are established below a 学科. Each 講座 typically has one 教授 (professor). The hierarchy typically looks like this:

理学部 Faculty of Science

数学科 Department of Mathematics

代数学講座 Chair/Course of Algebra

教授, 准教授, 講師, ...


幾何学講座 Chair/Course of Geometry

教授, 准教授, 講師, ...


...


天文学科 Department of Astronomy
...


工学部 Faculty of Engineering
文学部 Faculty of Letters
...

For example, The University of Tokyo has 10 学部/faculties, one of which is 理学部. 理学部 has 10 学科/departments, one of which is 数学科. There are 24 professors in 数学科, and each of them is a head of a 講座.

Thanks. So the target for 配した is 研究・教育のための組織, right?

@JohnDavies What do you mean by "target"? The literal translation is "an organization for research and education where professors, associate professors, lecturers, etc., are allocated on a per-department basis".

I mean the non-relativized version of the definition is 大学で、学科ごとに教授・准教授・講師などを研究・教育のための組織に配した, right?

@JohnDavies Yes.
